# Is there a way to override the physical key state on Windows in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I essentially want to make a small program which outputs the pressed key at a configurable speed for as long as that key is pressed. I'm using a global `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook in a separate DLL for this.

All of this works, except for the fact, that the original key stays pressed, making this not work in programs that keep an internal key state, as all the new, fake inputs are just ignored. Keys are also auto repeated, though that is not exactly a problem, considering the nature of this program. It would still be nice to also not have auto repeats either, though.

Basically:

physical key down -> (`internal_state[key] = true`) -> separate loop thread sends down & up inputs at loop speed -> physical key up -> (`internal_state[key] = false`)

But everything between the physical key up and down is ignored.

Now I could easily go around this issue by using a different, non one-to-one key map (e.g. holding shift outputs lots of space presses) or instead of having to hold the key to just use a toggle. While that would work, it's not what I want.

What I essentially need is a way of overriding the current key state, making the key not pressed after it's first pressed, even though it's still being pressed, physically anyway. Basically something like `SetKeyboardState`, except not bound to the calling thread, but rather changing the global state.

I'm not sure if this is possible without writing a custom driver, which is beyond the scope of what I want to accomplish, even if that might be interesting to do.

I've tried using `keybd_event` with `dwFlags` set to `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`, as well as the `SendInput` equivalent, neither of which cleared the key state.

Edit (minimal code):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHookProc(
    int nCode,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kb = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;

        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if (
                kb->dwExtraInfo != 1 
                && kb->vkCode == KeyboardSpamKey
                )
            {
                KeyboardSpam = true;
                // this is where "the magic" would need to happen
            }

            break;

        case WM_KEYUP:
            if (
                kb->dwExtraInfo != 1 
                && kb->vkCode == KeyboardSpamKey
                )
            {
                KeyboardSpam = false;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(
        KeyboardHook,
        nCode,
        wParam,
        lParam
    );
}
```

```
void ThreadLoop()
{
    while (ThreadEnable)
    {
        auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto next = now + ThreadSpeed;

        // inputKeyboard just returns a zero initialized INPUT, with ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD
        INPUT ip = inputKeyboard();
        ip.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(
            KeyboardSpamKey,
            MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC
        );
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        // dwExtraInfo set to 1 to be ignored in KeyboardHookProc
        ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 1;

        if (KeyboardSpam)
        {
            SendInput(
                1,
                &ip,
                sizeof(
                    ip
                    )
            );

            ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            SendInput(
                1,
                &ip,
                sizeof(
                    ip
                    )
            );
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_until(
            next
        );
    }
}
```

ThreadLoop is the function of a detached thread; ThreadEnable and KeyboardSpam are static bools in the main file